# Sencha Touch - How to get reference to class instance

Tags: class, sencha-touch, extjs

I'm instantiating a class when a button is clicked. How do I get a reference to this class instance outside of the button callback?

```
handler: function() {
    var formValues = Ext.getCmp('DonateItemForm').getValues(),
        itemDetails = Ext.create('App.model.ItemDetails', formValues);
}
```

Edit: Without using a global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the model instances in the controller that manages your panel(view).
However, if you are not coding according to the model-view-controller pattern, then you can attach it to the donate form:

```
Ext.getCmp('DonateItemForm').itemDetails = itemDetails;
```

But the basic idea should be clear:
Every time you want to access the model instance, just go through the object that manages it (either the form controller or the form itself).

[edit]

To store your data in the controller, you need to first send it to that controller:

Basically, your handler should send the data to your controller by dispatching a message to it. The message will contain the payload that contains the form data you want to send.

```
handler: function() {
    var formValues = Ext.getCmp('DonateItemForm').getValues();
    var itemDetails = Ext.create('App.model.ItemDetails', formValues);   

    Ext.dispatch({
        controller: "YourController",
        action: 'MethodOnYourController',
        yourDetails: itemDetails
    });
}
```

"yourDetails" will now hold the itemDetails that you need. Of course you can name it anything you want and you can add more members to the dispatched message if you like.

Now you need to make a method called "MethodOnYourController" that can catch this event:

```
YourController = Ext.extend(Ext.Controller, {
    MethodOnYourController: function(options)
    {
        this.itemDetails = options.yourDetails; // get the "yourDetails" that you added and store it in this controller
    }
});
```

I haven't tested this code, but the idea should be pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am using the MVC pattern - how do I go about storing the model instances in the controller? Sounds like exactly what I want.

Comment: You're welcome! I've edited my post. See the content past the "\[edit\]" mark for my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Makes perfect sense. I've tried finding how to do this online, with no success. Could you tell me where you got this approach from? I'm actually at the Sencha Workshop in Seattle right now.

Comment: I started out with the Sencha Teagrams tutorial as it claimed to use MVC: https://github.com/senchalearn/teagrams
The Teagrams example is not the greatest though, because it's not very strict with the MVC paradigm.
I mostly based myself on how MVC is supposed to work:
- No logic inside of the views(panels) except for maybe some animation logic
- Controllers manage the views(panels)
- Controllers fetch data(JSON/XML/etc) and push the data to the views
I have always 1 main controller that controls the main application logic and manages all the other sub-controllers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemDetails;

//...
handler: function() {
    var formValues = Ext.getCmp('DonateItemForm').getValues();
    itemDetails = Ext.create('App.model.ItemDetails', formValues);
}
//...
```

Just create a global variable (outside of the handler), and assign it in the handler

Comment: I was hoping for a Sencha way that didn't require using a global. Something like Ext.getModel('MyItems') and pass in 'MyItems' to the Ext.create().